# jquery toggle with a master switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery toggling to show and hide features of a specific product. I have it working, however it's not perfect and wondered if anyone could help please?

Basically what I'm having problems with is that when you use the master open all and then close all of the individual items on their own, I need the master switch to revert back to show all text.

In addition I want to have a + and - icon on each of the items but can't figure out how to only replace the clicked image and not all of them in the list!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').hide();
    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        var target = this.id + '_content';
        var imgtarget = this.id + '_expand';
        $('#' + target).slideToggle();
        $('.toggleall').text('Hide all');
        $('<img src="images/collapse.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
    });

    $('.toggleall').click(function() {
        if ($('.toggle').is(':visible')) {
            $('.toggle').slideUp();
            $('.toggleall').text('Show all');
            $('<img src="images/expand.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
        } else {
            $('.toggle').slideDown();
            $('.toggleall').text('Hide all');
            $('<img src="images/collapse.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
        }
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<div class="toggleall"><img src="images/expand.gif">Show all</div>
        <br><br>
        <div class="toggler" id="toggle1"><img src="images/expand.gif" class="toggle1_expand">Toggle 1</div>
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle1_content">only toggle1</div>
        <div class="toggler" id="toggle2"><img src="images/expand.gif" class="toggle2_expand">Toggle 2</div>
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle2_content">only toggle2</div>
        <div class="toggler" id="toggle3"><img src="images/expand.gif" class="toggle3_expand">Toggle 3</div>
        <div class="toggle" id="toggle3_content">only toggle3</div>
```

Here is the jfiddle of the code (thanks François Wahl): [jsfiddle.net/GUYfG](http://jsfiddle.net/GUYfG)

Comment: This doesn't effect the functionality but none of your image tags is closing `/>`.

Comment: Your question is little unclear could you explain more

Comment: Thanks, we're using HTML 5 markup so they don't need them anymore

Comment: basically I need the toggle all functionality to react to all of the divs being closed and I need to have an image on each div to represent expanded or contracted content

Comment: @Barlow1984: To give the guys something to play around with, here is a jsfiddle.net/GUYfG of the current code. Feel free to add it to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working version in a proper format :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.toggle').hide();

   $('.toggler').click( function() {
      var target = this.id + '_content';
      var imgtarget = this.id + '_expand';
          $('#' + target).slideToggle(function(){
                if( $('.toggle').is(':visible') ) {
                  $('.toggleall').text('Hide all');
                  $('<img src="images/collapse.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
              } else {
                  $('.toggleall').text('Show all');
                  $('<img src="images/expand.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
              }
          });

          if( $('.toggle').is(':visible') ) {
              $('.toggleall').text('Hide all');
          }
    });

    $('.toggleall').click(function() {
         if ($('.toggle').is(':visible')) {
                $('.toggle').slideUp();
                $('.toggleall').text('Show all');
                $('<img src="images/expand.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
            } else {
                $('.toggle').slideDown();
                $('.toggleall').text('Hide all');
                $('<img src="images/collapse.gif">').prependTo('.toggleall');
            }
     });

 });
```

**EDIT:**

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetsubhajit/GUYfG/5/)

I have edited the code check now. Also check the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's pretty much what I tried before posting to be honest. My only problem is when you open one item and then click the master hide, it only toggles them and doesn't hide all

Comment: Now you can check, hope your requirement is met now.

Comment: Thanks so much for that Subhajit. It works much better but the image doesn't seem to change on the items when they are used, I can't see why though, they stay as the expand image. Also for some reason the hide all seems to remove the image and then add it in again

Comment: yes I have coded it accordingly that the image would change, collaspe.gif should have the image with a symbol of hide. and expand.gif should contain an image which indicates to expand.
As you did it previously with image hence the code is done to swap the expand and collaspe image. Also you can use another way by toggling class. Let me know if you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: has your issue been solved..? As i checked its working perfectly here.

Comment: It's not quite 100% still but I think I can sort it out from where it is now. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To expand-collapse you can toggle a class with different background images inside a DIV, or use unordered lists (UL / LI).